# Help with Serial.print()

Tags: serial, serial-data

How does the Serial.print() transmit the data? Can you please explain this with respect to TX buffers?

Also, **What would happen if i try to output the data that is greater than 64 bytes? How is this transmitted?**

And please explain the difference with Serial.write()

Thanks!

Comment: is it your home work from school?

Comment: No how can that be a homework I was just just curious about serial communications. AND BTW I DONT DO homeworks

Comment: @Juraj i was reading this https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/14405/41798 and was curious

Comment: you could look into the source code. class Print has all the print functions implemented using write function. HardwareSerial only implements write byte function, which adds a byte into TX buffer

Comment: Print is base class of the hierarchy Print <- Stream <- HardwareSerial

Comment: and in hierarchy Print <- Stream <- Client <- EthernetClient, the EthernetClient writes the byte into buffer for sending over network

Comment: if the TX buffer of Serial is full, the write function waits in a while loop until one byte can be added to buffer

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.print()` feeds the data into the TX buffer one character at a time (through the `Print` class's inherited `.write()` function which `HardwareSerial` implements). If there isn't enough room in the TX buffer for the next character it waits for there to be room available.

Characters are removed one at a time from the TX buffer and sent through the physical UART by the UART's TX interrupt.

To put it in more detail:

- When you call `Serial.print()` it's actually calling `Print.print()`, because `Print` is a parent class of the `HardwareSerial` class.
- `Print.print()` repeatedly calls `Print.write()` for each character to print.
- `Print.write()` is a *pure virtual* function (which means it's only got the definition in the `Print` class and child classes must implement it).
- `HardwareSerial.write()` implements the `Print.write()` function which takes the character and (with possible blocking while waiting for space) adds it to the TX buffer.
- `Serial` is an instance of the `HardwareSerial` class.

Comment: Serial.write() adds a byte to TX buffer

Comment: @Juraj Serial.print() is actually Print.print() which calls Print.write() which is a pure virtual function implemented by the HardwareSerial child class.

Comment: I didn't say something else